# Full typing with TypeScript and ASP.Net WebApi

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, typescript, swagger

Is there any approaches to auto-generate OpenAPI/Swagger metadata for WebApi methods or maybe even to generate client typescript models?

I found [Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle) and [Swagger to JS & Typescript Codegen](https://github.com/wcandillon/swagger-js-codegen) to be nice but I wonder to find out any other libs.

It would be perfect if you can give pros and cons of each approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can also check out [NSwag](http://nswag.org), a Swagger toolchain for .NET and TypeScript.**

The tool generates Swagger specs from existing Web API controllers and client code based on these Swagger specs. You can generate TypeScript client code for JQuery with Callbacks or Promises, AngularJS or Angular2. The generated DTOs (request/response types) can either be interfaces or classes (with date conversion, lower camel casing, etc..)

The project can be used with a simple to use desktop GUI, build scripts or a command line tool.

[image]

Disclaimer: I'm one of the contributors of NSwag.

Answer (score 2):

Please try [Swagger-Codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen), which is a free and open-source code generator to generate REST API clients (e.g. C#, TypeScript, Javascript and more) or server stubs (ASP.NET5) given an OpenAPI/Swagger spec.

Here is a good starting point: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#getting-started

For `typescript`, Swagger Codegen supports different libraries: `typescript-node`, `typescript-angular`, `typescript-angular2` and `typescript-fetch`

Answer (score 0):

## openapi-typescript

openapi client generator for typescript

`npm install @cblx.br/openapi-typescript --save-dev`

create an openapi-typescript.config.js

```
var config = {
    url: "<url>/swagger.json",
    outputDir: "./src/client",
};

module.exports = config;
```

execute it:

`npx openapi-typescript`

---

Angular example:

create an app-connector.ts

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { OpenApiConnector } from '@cblx.br/openapi-typescript';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppConnector implements OpenApiConnector {

    constructor(@Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string, private http: HttpClient) {}

    async request(method: string, path: string, parameters: any, body: any) {
        return await this.http.request(method, this.baseUrl + path, {
            body: body,
            params: parameters
        }).toPromise();
    }
}
```

openapi-typescript.config.js

```
var config = {
    url: "<url>/swagger.json",
    outputDir: "./src/client",
     events: {
        beforeWriteServiceClass: () => {
            var content = '';
            content += `import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';\n`;
            content += `import { AppConnector } from 'app/app-connector';\n`;
            content += `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })\n`;
            return content;
        },
        createConnectorDecorator: () => {
            return `@Inject(AppConnector) `;
        }
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately you want TypeScript models, not Swagger meta data. [ASP.NET Web API Client Generators](https://github.com/zijianhuang/webapiclientgen) may be more handy, less overhead than swagger toolchain during SDLC.

While programmers generally use WebApiClientGen to generate client API codes, this project also provides POCO2TS.exe, a command line program that generates TypsScript interfaces from POCO classes. You may use either Poco2ts.exe or the poco2ts component to integrate the code generation with your build pipeline.